# Detect Keyboard Language - Romaji vs Japanese

Tags: swift

So I'm trying to detect whether the user's keyboard is set to the Japanese or to the Romaji version. I can read, when the user changes the keyboard as follows:

```swift
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: UITextInputMode.currentInputModeDidChangeNotification, object: nil, queue: .main){ notification in
    if String(textField.textInputMode?.primaryLanguage ?? "") == "ja-JP"{
        self.hasCorrectKeyboard = true
    }else{
        self.hasCorrectKeyboard = false
    }
}
```

However, both of these keyboards will return `"ja-JP"`. Is there a better way to detect what keyboard is set, such as a unique identifier for each keyboard?

[image: Romaji Keyboard]
[image: Japanese Keyboard]

Comment: Why? Your application should only concern itself with the input it gets, not how that input was generated. Remember that there can be multiple implementations of keyboards, even hardware keyboards. And not every input method that would be usable with your program are required to signal themselves as Japanese. What you are trying to do, would in my opinion result in a flimsy program that confuses users.

Comment: It's an app that teaches people how to write Japanese as it is not as straight forward as English.

Answer (score 1):

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html

Not sure if this can work out since I'm not familiar with Japanese but based on the doc there are something called `Japanese-Romanji` and `Japanese-Kana`

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextinputmode

after you check your language is `String(textField.textInputMode?.primaryLanguage ?? "") == "ja-JP"` then further check (textField.textInputMode?.activeInputModes) or you can try to console out `.activeInputModes` to check if there is variable that distincts `Romanji` and `Kana`.